# Set style of element from object

Tags: javascript, css, dom

I have a problem with setting styles for element from object. In first function I parse string with style code.

```
parseCheckingStyle: function(properties) {
    var propertiesList = {},
    tempArr=properties.split(/\s*;\s*/, this.length);
    tempArr.forEach(function(element, value, array){
        var splittedTempArr = element.split(/\s*:\s*/);
        propertiesList[splittedTempArr[0]] = splittedTempArr[1];
    });
    return propertiesList;
};
```

For example

```
parse('background: #ccc; color: #fff;')
```

return

```
{background: "#ccc", color: "#000"}
```

Then, with this function i try to set this object like style of element:

```
setCheckingStyle: function(selector, properties) {
    var propertiesList = this.parseCheckingStyle(properties);
    for (var key in propertiesList){
        selector.style.key = propertiesList[key];

    }
};
```

But style is not setting. How I can solve this problem?

P.S. I need realization without jQuery

Answer (score 2):

It should be `selector.style[key]` instead of `selector.style.key`. When you use `.`, the property name is used literally, not as a variable; you have to use `[]` to evaluate it as a variable.

You obviously know this already, since you wrote `propertiesList[key]` instead of `propertiesList.key`.